# Need to touch to interact with tableview after push view controller xamarin ios on second time

Tags: ios, xamarin, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

This is the case: 
I have two screens(view controllers), one is login page and another is tableview

After go to tableview from login page at first time, everything is ok.
But when i go to login page from table view, and from there to tableview again, i need to touch the tableview to allow me to interact with the table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done

My problem was with navigation controller, i just release the navigation controller on ViewWillDisappear method.

Thanks